# Does breeze work fine with local storage in chrome apps?

Tags: local-storage, breeze, google-chrome-app

I would like to know if someone managed to make Breeze.Js work inside à Chrome Application and if it handles well the specific local storage (see http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html).

Feedback and code examples are welcomed!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze simply provides mechanisms to export and import collections of entities to and from strings. You can store and retrieve these strings from any persistent data store, including localStorage, indexedDb or any other storage mechanism.

Breeze is completely agnostic about this, and there are numerous examples in the Breeze samples that show use of the breeze EntityManager.exportEntities and EntityManager.importEntities calls using localStorage ( and we test in Chrome as well as IE and Firefox. )

Answer (score 0):

I think IndexedDB could also be used for the storage.
http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/